# How can I do basic html validation within a column in a SQL Server database?

Tags: validation, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a database table with HTML snippets (not whole documents) in a column and I need to do some basic HTML validation of the contents. My initial need is to just be able to run a one time query+validation report, not anything more complicated than that.

Comment: What do you mean by `database with HTML snippets` ?

Comment: rephrasing: I have a SQL Server 2008 R2 Database and in a table, I have a varchar column that contains HTML and I want to do some basic validation on that HTML.

This is actually for two different purposes, but the first is simple. My old blog is using Subtext and stores my posts in HTML in the DB. I want to export to BlogML and the parser is failing but I can't figure out where.

Comment: @LucM What do you mean what does he mean? =)

Comment: Please update your question rather than posting a comment. Also where do you want to do the validation on the Client, in an SP, in a Trigger etc?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I read Jeff's post here http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2009/11/parsing-html-the-cthulhu-way.html and realized that I need to use a real parser after all.

It looks like http://tidy.sourceforge.net/ will get me what I need, I'll just have to write an ugly script that goes row by row and shells out to Tidy.

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest using Regex -

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163473.aspx

Example -

```
select dbo.RegexMatch( N'123-45-6789', N'^\d{3}-\d{2}-\d{4}$' )
```

Or stricly t-sql -

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/khen1234/archive/2005/05/11/416392.aspx

However, CLR User-Defined Functions are probably the way to go.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure I can follow this all the way through on my own. That Regex seems like it would just tell me if tags were closed and that's it, yes? (again, my regex skills are rudimentary)

Answer (score 0):

SQL Server does have some [XML validation capabilities](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2009/12/02/sql-server-validate-an-xml-document-in-tsql-using-xsd-by-jacob-sebastian/) built in for a field of type XML. Given that HTML is a subset of XML you might be able to twist that functionality to make SQL Server do the work for you.